# Memory allocation/deallocation of UIViewController.view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get my head around the following.

I'm debugging an app that seems to require more memory than necessary. I added the following code to 'crashtest' a viewcontroller:

```
NSLog(@"allocating 10000 instances of the MyViewController");
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    MyViewController *aController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (aController.view == nil) {} 
    [aController release];
    [pool drain];
}
NSLog(@"done allocating 10000 instances of MyViewController");
```

When I run the above code in Instruments/Allocations, its memory usage *All Allocations* / *live* is about 5 Mb before entering the loop. It's about 24 Mb after the loop has run.

If I run the same code with the line `if (aController.view == nil) {}` disabled, memory doesn't increase significantly.

`UIViewController` automatically calls `loadView()` because I use `aController.view`. So I can understand a temporary increase in mem usage. But shouldn't that memory get deallocated when I call `release` on the controller? Or does the memory allocated (and listed under *live bytes*) for a view only actually get freed under a low memory condition?

Comment: That sounds like there might be a leak in your controller/view. Have you forgotten to set some IBOutlets to nil in `-dealloc`?

Comment: Yes, they are all accounted for. I have 4, and each of them is released as follows in `dealloc`: `[myButton release], myButton = nil`

Comment: If something "sounds like there might be a leak", you should check whether it actually is. Running your test program with Instruments (there's a "Leaks" instrument) can tell you whether or not you actually have a leak.

Comment: Instruments/Leaks doesn't tell me that there is a leak. But that doesn't mean there isn't, there are situations in which instruments doesn't detect a leak condition as leak.

Answer (score 0):

messaging `[viewController view]` loads the view (when/if needed).